# find the flow of a vector field $\vec{a}$ through a closed surface S

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

I have $\vec{a} = (y^2+xz, xy - z, yz + x)$

In other words, it's $\space \vec{a} = (y^2+xz)\vec{i} + (xy - z)\vec{j} + (yz + x)\vec{k}$

$S: x^2 + y^2 = 1, z = 0, z = \sqrt{2}$

I have found that $\operatorname{div}(\vec{a}) = 2x+y$ and then I have to use some substitutions and Ostrogradsky formula but I don't know how to use it when I have found the $\operatorname{div}$, can you help me please?

Comment: The set up of the integral is unimportant if you can be clever. For the triple integral $$\iiint_V 2x+y\:dV$$ the integrand is an odd function in both variables. Is there any conclusion you can draw from this? (Hint: Think about the volume in question and think about the symmetry in each variable alone).

Comment: Actually, $\text{div}(\mathbf{a}) = z +x + y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First, note: $\space \operatorname{div}\vec{a} = x+ y+ z,\space$ as mentioned in the comment of colleague @peek-a-boo. Next, I will recommend cylindrical coordinates: $\space x = \rho \cos \varphi, \space y= \rho \sin \varphi, \space z=z, \space J=\rho,\space$where we have: 
$$0 \le \rho \le 1, \space 0 \le \varphi \le 2\pi, \space 0 \le z \le \sqrt{2}.$$